# conditional filtering in array and sum

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I am getting three drinks based on age 10. I want to filter that list based on age, if the age is less than 15, it should only display drinks that can not contain alcohol products and also how to calculate the sum of the item based on the same condition using loop.

Comment: Where is the JavaScript here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just tweak your code a bit.. something like this:

```
  void getNewDrink(List<int> itemList, int age, int cash) {

    final userDrinks = beverage
      .where((drink) => itemList.contains(drink.id))
      .where((drink) => age >= 15 || !drink.isAlchol)
      .toList();
    
    final sum = userDrinks.map((drink) => drink.price).reduce((value, element) => (value ?? 0) + (element ?? 0));
    
    print(sum);
    
    var anotherSum = 0;
    for (final drink in userDrinks) {
      print(drink.name);
      anotherSum += drink.price ?? 0;
    }
    print(anotherSum);
  }
```

Comment: thanks alot that was super helpful....! but how can i get total sum? i am getting as 2 , 5 10 as a sum but i want only 10

Comment: I wrote total sum in the example. print(sum); gave you that... and same goes for print(anotherSum);  just make sure to run it after the for-loop

Comment: Yes thanks alot...is it also possible to calculate total sum using for loop? and what does ?? 0 means at the end?

Comment: Dude, I wrote the total calc using for loop as well... it is the anotherSum variable!

Comment: ?? 0 is needed because the int named price in the drink class is nullable, meaning that if it is null, use a zero as default value when summing

Comment: I have now edited the answer to make it super clear. Just replace your getNewDrink method with what I wrote and all will work

Comment: Since this is your first question... remember to accept the answer to mark it as solved

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few functions that will help you.

To filter a list and remove the drinks with alcohol :

```
List<Drink> getDrinksWithoutAlcohol(List<Drink> initialList) {
  return initialList.where((drink) => !drink.isAlchol).toList();
}
```

To get the total price of a list of beverages in a for loop

```
int getTotalPrice(List<Drink> listDrinks) {
  int price = 0;
  for(Drink drink in listDrinks) {
    price += drink.price ?? 0;
  }

  return price;
}
```

And based on the code you provided, if you want to conditionally filter your list depending on the user's age, you could do the following

```
final finalList = userAge < 15 ? getDrinksWithoutAlcohol(userDrinks) : userDrinks;
```

Comment: thanks Xerib that was helpful. how can i get total as 10 not 2,5 10